# Improve query execution time for Laravel

Tags: mysql, spring, laravel

I have a Spring Boot application which saves data into a MySQL database with 7 tables. The front end has to display data from these tables based on some queries. For this part of the application, Laravel has been used and the way it works is that it executes MySQL queries like: select * from table. The data from the tables is modified every three hours by the Spring application.

The problem is that the queries take too long and it takes 16 seconds for the website to load...How can I improve that? Should I make static data from my tables and generate with the spring part of the application some JSON files? Should I create an API and make requests from the front end? Which is the fastest way to display data on my website?

Comment: Could you paste related code source here ?

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: What is your website url?  With GTMetrix.com you can find areas to improve that would reduce load time (minify pages is a biggie).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into [MySQL explain queries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html), and make sure that you backup your queries with an [index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html). Most likely your queries are slow on the MySQL server and you don't need to optimise something in the application.

Beside that more details in your question about your code could help to analyse the root cause.